# how to override a TXT dns record in linux

Tags: centos, dns

I would like to override a TXT DNS record in Linux, so when I run

```
dig x.com TXT +short
```

I would like to get the following result

```
"CLOUD=BER EDGE=PAR"
```

My Linux dist. is centos 7

Comment: Do you control the domain in question?

Comment: Please explain the background a bit, i.e., why you need to do this. For example, a trivial approach would be to just write a script to replace the `dig` command — that would, taken literally, answer your question. But I doubt it'd actually help you, and without knowing what you're actually trying to accomplish, it's hard to help.

Comment: Would you be ok with running your own (small) DNS server like dnsmasq?

Comment: @jsbillings yes it would be ok with running my own (small) DNS server like dnsmasq